# Trabb Pardo – Knuth - Algorithm in streams

Tags: java, algorithm, stream

Trabb Pardo and Knuth devised this simple procedure as a way to explore the functionality of various languages. The [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trabb_Pardo%E2%80%93Knuth_algorithm) describes it as:

> The Trabb Pardo–Knuth algorithm is a program introduced by Donald Knuth and Luis Trabb Pardo to illustrate the evolution of computer programming languages.

The algorithm is simple:

> ```
> ask for 11 numbers to be read into a sequence S
> reverse sequence S
> for each item in sequence S
>     call a function to do an operation
>     if result overflows
>         alert user
>     else
>         print result
> ```

The standard 'function' is to calculate the following:

$$
    f(x) = \sqrt{|x|} + 5 \times x^3
$$

The limiting factor is traditionally the value 400.0.

Here's the Java 8 code to accomplish the traditional 11 input values:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.function.IntToDoubleFunction;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class TPK {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);) {
            int[] values = IntStream.generate(scanner::nextInt).limit(11).toArray();
            int[] reversed = IntStream.range(0, values.length)
                    .map(index -> values[values.length - index - 1]).toArray();
            IntToDoubleFunction function =
                    val -> Math.sqrt(Math.abs(val)) + 5 * val * val * val;
            Arrays.stream(reversed)
                    .mapToDouble(function)
                    .forEach(val -> System.out.println(
                            val > 400.0 ? "TOO LARGE" : String.format("%.5f", val)));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of generating an array of \$N\$ elements and then reversing it, I'd find it more natural to push values onto a stack and pop off one by one.

It would seem that the "standard" and "traditional" elements would be good as constants, defined near the top of the file:

- the number 11
- the function to apply
- the limit

So that you can play with them easily without making edits inside the main, unchanging part of the code.

Lastly, you have an unnecessary `;` in the `try` statement.

The ability to unit test would be nice, though in this simple example it might take substantial refactoring and lead to over-engineering, and so might not be worth it. Just a thought anyway.